# Why is my node.js get response being truncated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a request to the facebook api to get a list of friends. When I make the request through node.js, my request is always truncated. Does anyone understand why the response is being truncated?

Here is the code of my function:

```
var loadFriends;
loadFriends = function(access_token, callback) {
  var https, options, start;
  https = require('https');
  start = new Date();
  options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/me/friends?access_token=' + access_token
  };
  return https.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Request took:", new Date() - start, "ms");
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    return res.on("data", function(responseData) {
      var data;
      console.log(responseData);
      data = JSON.parse(responseData);
      return callback(data);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Please tag this with the language or framework you're using, as this is not JavaScript/node.js.

Comment: I converted it from coffeescript to javascript and tagged it appropriately

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `res.on('data')` event will happen multiple times as chunks of data arrives; you need to concatenate this together to get the whole response.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#event_data_

Comment: To finish the thought: you know that data is done arriving when the `end` event is triggered. This is when you should call any callbacks that require the complete data.